# How can I pass a variable from iframe to a parent window?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe, colorbox

I have a colorbox parent page which contains a TabContainer with different iFrames on the case for the second tab in which a change is made to the database and need to update the a textbox of the parent window.

[image]

Comment: Please switch the image to some code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't directly interact across the boundaries of an iframe as this would present a security risk.

One workaround can be to alter the url within the iframe to include an `#anchor` value or `?querystring` and then read the iframe's url from the parent.

Comment: you can use `contentWindow.location.href` on the iframe's DOM object. eg: `var TheLocation = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.location.href;`

Comment: You can also set the location from the parent, so this can work in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have tried `postMessage`, this is a javascript API , but there is browser limitation.

**Parent** page can post message like this.

```
var win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow

win.postMessage(
  "value",
  "iframe-domain"
);
```

And **iframe page** can listen to message like this.

```
<script>
function listener(event){
  if ( event.origin !== "[parent-page-domain]" )
    return;

 // operate with event.data
}

if (window.addEventListener){
  addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
  attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
</script>
```

SOURCE - http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage